# Ajax.BeginForm the form cannot be specified

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a view that will write to a database using ASP.NET, and I'm using `Ajax.BeginForm` to capture the data. However, whenever I try and call the forms POST method, it fails with Error 404, stating the resource could not be found. The online tutorials I have found on this haven't been helpful, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. My code is as follows:

**View: AddStop.cshtml**

```
@model FYP2._1.Models.Stop
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Stop";
}

<h2>AddStop</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<fieldset>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddStop", "MapController", new AjaxOptions
    {
        OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
        OnFailure = "OnFailure",
        LoadingElementId = "progress"
    }))
    {
        <table id="tblPersons" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" align="center">Enter Details</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.Label("Forename")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(b => b.Forename)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.Label("Surname")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(b => b.Surname)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.Label("PostCode")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(b => b.Postcode)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.Label("Route Type")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(b => b.BusRoute, new List <SelectListItem>
                        { new SelectListItem { Text = "Route 1", Value = "1" },
                          new SelectListItem { Text = "Route 2", Value = "2" },
                          new SelectListItem { Text = "Route 3", Value = "3" },
                          new SelectListItem { Text = "Route 4", Value = "4" },
                          new SelectListItem { Text = "Route 5", Value = "5"}})
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        @Html.ActionLink("Back To Main Menu", "Index");

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10" style="color:green">
                @ViewBag.Message
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</fieldset>
```

**Controller: MapController.cs**

```
        // GET: Map/AddStop
        public ActionResult AddStop()
        {
            return View();
        }
        
        // POST: Map/AddStop
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddStop(Stop NewStop)
        {
            try
            {
                db.Stops.Add(NewStop);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Message = "Stop Added Successfully";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Thanks in Advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller name is specified without the controller postfix in the parameters of `BeginForm` method.

It should be like:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddStop", "Map", new AjaxOptions
{
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
    OnFailure = "OnFailure",
    LoadingElementId = "progress"
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Add  *HttpMethod = "Post"* to your AjaxOptions to handel it on your controller.
```

And it is better to return a partialview instade of view in your action.

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddStop", "MapController", new AjaxOptions
        {
            OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
            OnFailure = "OnFailure",
            HttpMethod = "Post",
            LoadingElementId = "progress"
        }))
```

Comment: Still getting the same error, is there anything else you can suggest?